# On the Efficiency of Data Infrastructure, Storage and Retrieval with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm curious about which is the most efficient way to store and retrieve data in and from a database.

The table:

```
+----+--------+--------+   +-------+   +----------+
| id | height | weight | ← | bmi   | ← | category |
+----+--------+--------+   +-------+   +----------+
|  1 |    184 |     64 |   | 18.90 |   |        2 |
|  2 |    147 |     80 |   | 37.02 |   |        4 |
|  … |    ……… |     …… |   | …… …… |   |        … |
|    |        |        | ← |       | ← |          |
+----+--------+--------+   +-------+   +----------+
```

**From a storage perspective**

If we want to be more efficient in terms of storing the data, columns `bmi` and `category` would be obsolete, adding data we could've otherwise figured out based on the former two columns `height` and `weight`.

**From a retrieval perspective**

Leaving out the `category` column we could ask

```
SELECT * 
FROM bmi_entry 
WHERE bmi >= 18.50 AND bmi < 25.00
```

and leaving out the `bmi` column as well, that becomes

```
SELECT * 
FROM bmi_entry 
WHERE weight / ((height * 100) * (height * 100)) >= 18.50 
  AND weight / ((height * 100) * (height * 100)) < 25
```

However, calculation could hypothetically take much longer that simply comparing a column to a value, in which case

```
SELECT * 
FROM bmi_entry 
WHERE category = 2
```

would be the far superior query in terms of retrieval time.

**Best practice?**

At first, I was about to go with method one, thinking why store *"useless"* data and take up storage space… ***but then I thought about the implementation*** and how potentially having to recalculate those *"obsolete"* fields for every single row every time I want to sort and retrieve specific sets of BMI entries within specific ranges or categories could dramatically slow down the time it takes to collect the data.

Ultimately:

1. Wouldn't the arithmetic functions of division and multiplication take more time and thus slow down the user experience?
2. Would there ever be a case in which you would prioritise storage space over retrieval time?

---

If the answer to (1.) is a simple "yup", you can *comment* that below. :-)

If you have a more in depth elaboration on either (1.) or (2.), however, feel free to post that or those as well, as I, and others, would be very interested in reading more!

Comment: don't save the bmi and other calculated columns, as long it doesn't to much time to calculate them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wouldn't the arithmetic functions of division and multiplication take more time and thus slow down the user experience?

You might have assumed "yup" would be the answer, but in fact the complexity of the arithmetic is not the issue. The issue is that you shouldn't need to evaluate the expressions at all to check if it should be included in your query result.

Searching on an expression instead of an indexed column, MySQL will be forced to visit every single row and evaluate the expression. This is a *table-scan*. The cost of the query, even disregarding the possible slowness of the arithmetic, is bound to increase in linear proportion to the number of rows.

In complexity of algorithms, we say this is "Order N" cost to the algorithm. Even if it's actually "N * a fixed multiplier due to the cost of of the arithmetic," it's still the N we're worried about, especially if N is ever-increasing.

You showed the example where you stored an extra column for the pre-calculated bmi or category, but that alone wouldn't avoid the table-scan. Searching for `category=2` is still going to cause a table-scan unless `category` is an indexed column.

Indexing a column is fine, but it's a little more tricky to index an expression. Recent versions of MySQL have given us that ability for most types of expressions, but if you're using an older version of MySQL you may be out of luck.

With MySQL 8.0, you can index the *expression* without having to store the calculated columns. The index is prepared based on the result of the expression. The index itself takes storage space, but it would have if you had indexed the column too. Read more about this here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html in the section on "Functional Key Parts".

> Would there ever be a case in which you would prioritise storage space over retrieval time?

Sure. Suppose you have a very large amount of data, but you don't need to run queries especially frequently or quickly.

Example: I managed a database of bulk statistics that we added to throughout the month, but we only needed to query it about once at the end of the month to make a report. It didn't matter that this report took a couple of hours to prepare, because the managers who read the report would be viewing it in a document, not by running the query themselves. Meanwhile, the storage space for the indexes would have been too much for the server the data was on, so they were dropped.

Once a month I would kick off the task of running the query for the report, and then switch windows and go do some of my other work for a few hours. As long as I got the result by the time the people who needed to read it were expecting it (e.g. the next day) I didn't care how long it took to do the query.

Ultimately the best practice you're looking for varies, based on your needs and the resources you can utilize for the task.

Comment: Thank you for that, Bill. :-) This was really, really informative and useful. I did not know about indexed columns; thanks to you I will now read into that. And I did not think of that particular situation you brought to light at the end with the large amount of data, which makes a lot of sense. Your answer is greatly appreciated, and it might actually just be the answer I was looking for! :D

Comment: You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Answer (score 1):

There is no best practice.  It depends on the considerations of what you are trying to do.  Here are some considerations:

1. Consistency

   - Storing the in separate columns means that the values can get out-of-synch.
   - Using a computed column or view means that the values are always consistent.
2. Updatability (the inverse of consistency)

   - Storing the data in separate columns means that the values can be updated.
   - Storing the data as computed columns means that the values cannot be separately updated.
3. Read Performance

   - Storing the data in separate columns increases the size of the rows, which tends to increase the size of the table.  This can decrease performance because more data must be read -- for any query on the table.
   - This is not an issue for computed columns, unless they are persisted in some way.
4. Indexing

   - Either method supports indexing.